# Two column Masonry jQuery with different width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I am current working on a custom theme using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com). I successfully implemented masonry but i unfortunately, i can't figure out how can i implement a two column with different sizes.

to have a clear view of what i'm trying to do, you can take a look at the image:

[image]

the problem i encounter is i only can make a similar width. in my example, i want to have the first column *(let's say)* width = 250px and the 2nd column is comlumn = 400px.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You can probably do this without masonry, just two columns with any grid system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess the work around will be as follows

```
$('.col2').css({'width':400});
$('.col1').css({'width':250});
```

after you apply the plugin . and edit other proprieties if required