# define 2 different size column in masonry drupal 7

Tags: html, css, drupal, jquery-masonry

I am using masonry for display article in drupal 7 to create pint rest effect, but I have a specific requirement,
I want article would be display in two different size column
 but in masonry provide only one column setting in view section in drupal 7.

So i have manage size with CSS, but i am not able to reach my requirement using css.

```
.masonry-item {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #DADADA; 
}

.views-row-odd{
  width: 330px;
} 
.views-row-even{

  width: 230px;

}
```

I am using Above css to maintain column size in drupal 7 but I need column size should be

480px for first column,  and 240px second column

container size I have define 960px

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182062/two-column-masonry-jquery-with-different-width ?